# Why Switch requires statement but accepts expressions

Tags: java, switch-statement, conditional-statements, switch-expression

I'm studying switch expressions and I think I found a weird behaviour:

```java
public static boolean isTimeToParty(Day day) {
    switch (day) {
        case MONDAY -> dog(); //expression allowed
        case TUESDAY -> 2 + 2; //error: not a statement
        case WEDNESDAY -> true; //error: not a statement
        default -> System.out.println("");
    }
    return false;
}

public static int dog() {
    return 2;
}
```

Why can I type as value `dog()` which is an expression but other types of expression are not allowed? Intellij prompts me with `"not a statement"` error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method invocation expression can also be used as a statement, as per the language specification:

> [14.8. Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)
>
> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following
> them with semicolons. 
> ExpressionStatement: 
> StatementExpression ; 
> StatementExpression: 
>  Assignment 
> PreIncrementExpression 
>  PreDecrementExpression 
> PostIncrementExpression 
>  PostDecrementExpression 
> **MethodInvocation** 
>  ClassInstanceCreationExpression

The second last line indicates that a method invocation expression can be used as a statement, which is why `dog()` is accepted. The return value is simply discarded. `2 + 2` cannot be used as a statement.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ recognises that you are trying to use a switch statement rather than a switch expression. If you change your code to be:

```
    int val = switch (day) {
        case MONDAY -> dog();
        case TUESDAY -> 2 + 2;
        case WEDNESDAY -> true;
        default -> System.out.println("");
    }
```

You will find that the error is now with the print statement and the `true` value because they cannot be converted to `int`. This is because Intellij now recognises your code as a switch expression.

In other words, all the branches of a switch expression need to be expressions of the same type and branches of a switch statement need to be statements. The method call `dog()` is both, hence it will work in either context.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `2 + 2` and `true` are not Java statements. In the [reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) we can read the following:

> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
> statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of
> expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression
> with a semicolon (;).
>
> - Assignment expressions
> - Any use of ++ or --
> - Method invocations
> - Object creation expressions
>
> Such statements are called expression statements. Here are some
> examples of expression statements:
>
> // assignment statement
> aValue = 8933.234;
>
> // increment statement
> aValue++;
>
> // method invocation statement
> System.out.println("Hello World!");
>
> // object creation statement
> Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle();

`2 + 2` and `true` are none of those since they are expressions instead, hence the compilation error in your switch statement.

Comment: the -> syntax is allowed in switch expressions,

Comment: I am not saying it isn't. I am just saying that `2 + 2` and `true` are not statements and hence are not allowed in a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is in a statement context. A statement might also be a method call, discarding away its result. There also exists the switch expression, where the requirements are reversed.